# Integral $\int_0^\infty \frac{u^\alpha}{1+u} du$ for $\alpha<-1$

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

Does any of you know how to solve

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{u^\alpha}{1+u} du$$

analytically for $\alpha<-1$? E.g., for $\alpha=-\pi$, the solution can be expressed by the Digamma Function according to Wolfram Alpha.

Prior solutions on 
 [Closed form for $ \int_0^\infty {\frac{{{x^n}}}{{1 + {x^m}}}dx }$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/110457/closed-form-for-int-0-infty-fracxn1-xmdx?noredirect=1&lq=1)  only cover $0 < \alpha < 1$.

Comment: Are you sure about the result for $\alpha = \pi$? The integral should not converge in that case.

Comment: What is $\alpha$ in this case?

Comment: I think the integral still diverges at $\alpha=-\pi$. As a Beta integral of the second kind (5th property [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Properties)), it  surely converges for $\alpha\in(-1,0)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\alpha =-a$, $u=\tan^2 t$, then
$$I=2 \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \tan^{1-2a} t~ dt = 2 \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \sin^{1-2a} t ~~ \cos^{2a-1} t~ dt = \Gamma(1-a) \Gamma(a)= \pi \csc \pi a, 0<a<1.$$

We have used Beta-integral and Gamma functions. For $a>1$ the integral diverges. See

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function

Comment: How do you go from $\infty$ to $\pi/2$?

Comment: @JennyReininger what is $u$ when $t = \infty$?

Comment: When $u=0, t=0$; when $u=\infty, t=\pi/2$ as $u=\tan^2 t$.